# Is there a better way to convert JSON into DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Want to convert JSON object to DataFrame.

This my JSON object

```
data = {'situation': {'OpenPlay': {'shots': 282,
   'goals': 33,
   'xG': 36.38206055667251,
   'against': {'shots': 276, 'goals': 29, 'xG': 33.0840025995858}},
  'FromCorner': {'shots': 46,
   'goals': 2,
   'xG': 2.861613758839667,
   'against': {'shots': 46, 'goals': 4, 'xG': 3.420699148438871}},
  'DirectFreekick': {'shots': 19,
   'goals': 1,
   'xG': 1.0674087516963482,
   'against': {'shots': 10, 'goals': 0, 'xG': 0.6329493299126625}},
  'SetPiece': {'shots': 14,
   'goals': 1,
   'xG': 0.6052199145779014,
   'against': {'shots': 21, 'goals': 1, 'xG': 2.118571280501783}},
  'Penalty': {'shots': 6,
   'goals': 6,
   'xG': 4.5670130252838135,
   'against': {'shots': 2, 'goals': 1, 'xG': 1.5222634673118591}}}
```

Want output:

[image]

My code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['situation']['OpenPlay'])

for i in range(1,4):
    df = df.append(pd.json_normalize(data['situation'][type_of_play[i]]))
    
df = df.reset_index()
```

**any efficient way of doing this?**

Comment: If you have a lot of iterations, you can create a list of each normalized df, then concat the list of dataframes. appending on each iteration is more time consuming

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your data lack of a '}' at the end.
Try this code:

```
obj = [pd.json_normalize(data['situation'][e]) for e in data['situation']]
pd.concat(obj, ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: @sammywemmy I just sign up this account today, it requires 10 reputations to embed images in posts, I did not have 10 reputations at that time and I could only link the image.

Comment: @sammywemmy No, I did not know. Even if I knew it, I cannot change the system setting, I have to get enough reputations so that I can put an image instead of a link. I also feel this setting makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: Please do not think so, I never think you are criticizing me. I hope we can learn tech with each other. Please forgive me if I have any offense.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data into a dataframe regularly, then run `json_normalize` on the column that contains the remaining dicts, and `join` it with the main dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['situation']).T.reset_index()
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.against), lsuffix='_against', how='left').drop(columns=['against'])
```

Result:

|  | index | shots_against | goals_against | xG_against | shots | goals | xG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | OpenPlay | 282 | 33 | 36.3821 | 276 | 29 | 33.084 |
| 1 | FromCorner | 46 | 2 | 2.86161 | 46 | 4 | 3.4207 |
| 2 | DirectFreekick | 19 | 1 | 1.06741 | 10 | 0 | 0.632949 |
| 3 | SetPiece | 14 | 1 | 0.60522 | 21 | 1 | 2.11857 |
| 4 | Penalty | 6 | 6 | 4.56701 | 2 | 1 | 1.52226 |

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, it is best to process the data outside Pandas, within the dictionary, and then create the dataframe.

You could use [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) to extract the data, before passing it into pandas; should be more efficient; you could run tests to check the speed:

Summary idea for [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/); if you are accessing a key, use `.`, if it's an array/list, use `[]`:

```
import jmespath 
expression = """{shots: *.*.shots[], 
                 goals: *.*.goals[], 
                   xG : *.*.xG[], 
                 against_shots: *.*.against.shots[], 
                 against_goals: *.*.against.goals[], 
                 against_XG: *.*.against.xG[]
                 }"""
expression = jmespath.compile(expression)
expression = expression.search(data)
#dataframe
pd.DataFrame(expression)
   shots  goals         xG  against_shots  against_goals  against_XG
0    282     33  36.382061            276             29   33.084003
1     46      2   2.861614             46              4    3.420699
2     19      1   1.067409             10              0    0.632949
3     14      1   0.605220             21              1    2.118571
4      6      6   4.567013              2              1    1.522263
```

[jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) can be convenient, especially as the nesting in the dict/json becomes more convoluted; most efficient however, would be to use the dictionary data structure directly:

```
from collections import defaultdict
df = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data['situation'].items():
     df['shots'].append(value['shots'])
     df['goals'].append(value['goals'])
     df['xG'].append(value['xG'])
     df['against_shots'].append(value['against']['shots'])
     df['against_goals'].append(value['against']['goals'])
     df['against_xG'].append(value['against']['xG'])

# create dataframe
pd.DataFrame(df)
 
   shots  goals         xG  against_shots  against_goals  against_xG
0    282     33  36.382061            276             29   33.084003
1     46      2   2.861614             46              4    3.420699
2     19      1   1.067409             10              0    0.632949
3     14      1   0.605220             21              1    2.118571
4      6      6   4.567013              2              1    1.522263
```